# What is the correct use of the interface keyword and `@@` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, interface, documentation, symbols

`interface` is a JavaScript keyword [reserved for future use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) and `@@` I often see in materials describing ES6 new [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) type.

For example from [jhusain/asyncgenerator](https://github.com/jhusain/asyncgenerator):

```
interface Observable {
  Generator @@observer(Generator observer)
}

interface Iterable {
  Generator @@iterator()
}
```

Is this just figurative use? What does `interface` and `@@` mean / or what is the correct usage when found in documentation / spec / feature proposals?